# How to set a image enabled when a action is already done?

Tags: iphone

I am working on a bible reader application for iphone. When we click on any verse of the bible it pops up a menu which contains some controllers like bookmark, notes view etc. The note view has a hidden tick mark. My requirement is as follows :

1. User should be able to select a verse, add a note to it and save it
2. When the same verse is selected again, the tick mark should appear indicating that a note has already been added.

My code is

```
-(IBAction)_clickbtnNotesMain:(id)sender
{

    [self.view addSubview:NoteView];
    _lblnotegns.text = localStringValueverseno;//localStringValueverseno which holds the verse no: from the tableview,the verse and verse no: shown in tableview
//NoteView is the notepopup ie,write note in Noteview
}
-(IBAction)_clickbtnsaveNote:(id)sender
{
[delegate.indexArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@:%@",delegate.selectedBook,delegate.selectedChapter,delegate.selectedIndex]];
    [delegate.notesArray addObject:textView.text];
    NSString *DataPath = [Malayalam_BibleAppDelegate getPath];
    [delegate.data writeToFile:DataPath atomically:YES];
    proAlertView *alert = [[proAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"NOTES" message:@"Notes Saved" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.255 green:0.218 blue:0.185 alpha:1.0] withStrokeColor:[UIColor colorWithHue:0.625 saturation:0.0 brightness:0.8 alpha:0.8]];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    }
```

With the above code I save the note. It is displayed in a tableviewcontroller which the user can see if he wants.

UPDATE:

```
-(IBAction)_clickbtnsaveNote:(id)sender
{
[delegate.indexArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@:%@",delegate.selectedBook,delegate.selectedChapter,delegate.selectedIndex]];
[delegate.notesArray addObject:textView.text];
    [notes setValue:textView.text forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@:%@",delegate.selectedBook,delegate.selectedChapter,delegate.selectedIndex]];
NSString *DataPath = [Malayalam_BibleAppDelegate getPath];
[delegate.data writeToFile:DataPath atomically:YES];
proAlertView *alert = [[proAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"NOTES" message:@"Notes Saved" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.255 green:0.218 blue:0.185 alpha:1.0] withStrokeColor:[UIColor colorWithHue:0.625 saturation:0.0 brightness:0.8 alpha:0.8]];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

then in my popup comes view that is mainpopup,it comes when i tap the cell codeis

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    if ([notes objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@:%@",delegate.selectedBook,delegate.selectedChapter,delegate.selectedIndex]] == nil) {
        [notetickimage setHidden:YES];
        [self.view addSubview:MainPopupView];
    }


}
```

Comment: @Manali Any idea about this issue?i have saved the note perfectly ,but need the second requirnment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this :

```
[yourBtnOrImage setHidden:YES];
```

or

```
[yourBtnOrImage setEnabled:YES];
```

You just have to check if there is already a note on a verse if yes use the code above, otherwise use the code below :

```
[yourBtnOrImage setHidden:NO];
```

or

```
[yourBtnOrImage setEnabled:NO];
```

I hope its what you are looking for.

**UPDATE :**

```
NSMutableDictionary *notes = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; //Initialize like that for you
//Add a note :
[notes setValue:textView.text forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@:%@",delegate.selectedBook,delegate.selectedChapter,delegate.selectedIndex]];
```

Code to check if a note exist :

```
if ([notes objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@:%@",delegate.selectedBook,delegate.selectedChapter,delegate.selectedIndex]] == nil) {
        [yourBtnOrImage setHidden:YES];
    }
```

Comment: Ok ^ ^ In my opinion the easiest way would be to use while in this case a NSMutableDictionnary. Each addition and link your note to a key that will be specific to each verse. I update my answer.

Comment: Can you be more explicit?
The verification code must be implemented when your menu appears. Not when you save the note.

The reasoning is as follows:

Clicking on the verse.
The menu appears, we check for the verse selected if a note has been saved previously, depending on your image is displayed or not.

Comment: @ICoder yes because i called it "notes" for example. You have to declare the NSMutableDictionary and initialize it only one time! Not at every time you save a note. If you init this every time it will never work ^^ because your dictionary will be always new.

Comment: 10 i declared it in .h nsmutabledictionary *notes,so the error goes but not working,i edit my question,i put all the code that i made.please look into it.thanks.

Comment: This is not good! Maybe we did not understand ..
I'm going to need some indices to help you.
Do you want the notes of each verse is stored on the iphone user?

Comment: 10 yea.i stored each note on the basisc of verse,on another view controller

Comment: not in case of tthis quistion i am still suffering,but i get another luck with the answer,i get an idea.

Answer (score 0):

There could be several ways to do this, one that I could think of is : 
In your delegate.notesArray add a field for verse number. While displaying the verse run through the array and check if the particular verse has a note attached to it.
EDIT:
Oh Yes, like A10 says NSMutableDictionnary might prove easier